# Pasting text with hyperlinks to WordPad

Tags: wordpad

When i copy a text with hyperlinks like under

---

bla bla bla bla [bla](http://bla.com)

to WordPad, hyperlinks turn into plain text like

bla bla bla bla *bla*

---

Am i doing something wrong or it is the Wordpad which may not capable of recognising hyperlinks ?

Comment: when I type a URL `http://www.google.com` into notepad and paste it into wordpad then it goes blue / becomes a hyperlink. tested in win7

Comment: right. but that is a link i am talking about copy and pasting hyperlink text , direct link works fine.

Comment: oh I see. I notice that from webpage to wordpad doesn't work, but from webpage to word works, and from webpage to word to wordpad works. So you could get it to wordpad that way